# VBA to insert data from Excel (O365) to SQL DB

Tags: sql, excel, vba, bulkinsert

I need to insert data from Excel spreadsheet to SQL Server as fast as possible. I've tried several options and dismissed all that involved loops and creation of recordset for poor performance. There is one way which in theory should be fast but it's surprisingly slow too and I can't figure out why.

The code below works and inserts all data from sheet DATA to our on-prem SQL Server, table tbl_sales. I tested for 10k rows X 30 cols it takes 15 minutes. Final input should be approx. 250k rows :(

Unfortunately the BULK INSERT or other SQL procedures are not an option since we don't have access to the server. I have to tackle it via VBA.

The target table (tbl_sales) is truncated, no indexes...

```
Sub Import_To_SQL()

    Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes"";"
 
    nSQL = "INSERT INTO [odbc;driver={SQL Server};server=sss;uid=uuu;pwd=ppp;trusted_connection=yes;database=salesdb].dbo.tbl_sales SELECT * FROM [DATA$];"
        
    cnn.Execute nSQL, , adExecuteNoRecords
    cnn.Close
    
End Sub
```

I tried to create the recordset and then action it against the database via `UpdateBatch` but performance was rather slow.

Answer (score 0):

using an excel connection to execute the INSERT INTO statement for each single row of data is very inefficient for large datasets. you can use the CopyFromRecordset method to perform a more efficient bulk insert like this:

```
Sub Import_To_SQL()
    Dim cnn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim connString As String
    Dim sqlServerConnString As String
    Dim sqlQuery As String

    ' Excel connection
    Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes"";"

    ' SQL Server connection
    sqlServerConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=sss;Initial Catalog=salesdb;User ID=uuu;Password=ppp;"
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    ' Open the recordset from the Excel worksheet
    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [DATA$];", cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

    ' Establish the connection to SQL Server
    Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cnn.Open sqlServerConnString

    ' Set up the SQL query
    sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_sales SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB','" & sqlServerConnString & "', 'SELECT * FROM tbl_sales')"

    ' Execute the bulk insert
    cnn.Execute sqlQuery

    ' Close connections
    rs.Close
    cnn.Close
End Sub
```

this opens the recordset directly from the excel worksheet in the rs.Open line and then opens establishes a connection to SQL server using a separate connection string and then copies the entire recordset to a target table in SQL Server in a single bulk operation then terminates the operation.

adjust the SQL connection string and target table if they differ from what you have.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, many thanks for your advise, I didn't realize that my approach inserts data row by row, I thought it does all dataset at once. I checked your code and I think the OPENROWSET part should refer to Excel sheet, right? Or where do you copy from Excel recordset to SQL? I tried to rewrite to:    

sXlsConnString = "Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;Database=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName
sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_sales SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','" & sXlsConnString & "', 'SELECT * FROM [DATA$]');"

Comment: What I forgot to mention is that Excel file is not sitting on the same server like SQL DB and we can't store the file there, therefore the intention is to insert the data from user's app.